How does each pointer within a page directory table able to point to ITS OWN page directory table?
I'm trying to figure one thing out. I understand that, say, for a 64-bit system that there is a 9 bit split which is used to index a 512 entries page directory table, like the PGD, or PMD, etc...
What I don't understand is how each pointer within those page directory tables is able to point to ITS OWN page directory table filled with 512 entries. As shown in the diagram below... Also, how large are the pointers (or ptr's)?
      PMD
--> +-----+           PTE
    | ptr |-------> +-----+
    | ptr |-        | ptr |-------> PAGE
    | ptr | \       | ptr |
    | ptr |  \        ...
    | ... |   \
    | ptr |    \         PTE
    +-----+     +----> +-----+
                       | ptr |-------> PAGE
                       | ptr |
                         ...
```


I strongly recommend reading volume 3A, chapter 5 of the Intel x86 manuals, it explains paging in detail.
Page directories don’t contain pointers, they contain page table entries which provide metadata about a page table or page frame, and part of a physical address. The translation process, going from a linear address to a physical address, always progresses through the page directories without ever having to refer to another page table entry at the same level, so page directories never need to point to themselves. When translating a linear address, the MMU starts with the page directory whose physical address is stored in the CR3 register. It then examines the subset of bits in the linear address decoded by that page directory, corresponding to an offset within the current page directory; that gives a page table entry (or page directory entry) specifying whether the next level is present or not, and if it is, where it is in memory.
This process ultimately leads to either an absent page, or (at most) the physical address of a 4KiB page. The process can stop early if a page is absent or if the linear address translates to an address in a page larger than 4KiB.
In 32-bit (non PAE) mode, each entry in a page directory is 32 bits in size, so each 4KiB directory stores 1024 entries (10 bits of the address). In 64-bit mode, each entry is 64 bits in size, so each 4KiB directory stores 512 entries (9 bits of the address).
In more detail, with 4-level paging, for a linear address mapping to a 4KiB page:

the CR3 register, bits 12 and up, point to the physical address of the 4KiB-aligned PML4 table
inside the PML4 table, bits 39 to 47 of the linear address point to a PML4 entry, pointing to a page-directory-pointer table
inside the PDP table, bits 30 to 38 of the linear address point to a PDPT entry, pointing to a page directory
inside the page directory, bits 21 to 29 of the linear address point to a PD entry, pointing to a page table
inside the page table, bits 12 to 20 of the linear address point to a PT entry, pointing to the 4KiB frame
bits 0 to 11 of the linear address determine the physical address inside the 4KiB page

Since all the tables are 4KiB-aligned, and the physical address space with 4-level paging is limited to 48 bits, only 36 bits are required to represent each table’s physical address. The rest of the various page table entries store metadata about the next level: whether it is present or not, whether it is read-only or read-write, etc.
